# AngularJS put $http service into separate file

Tags: angularjs

I have issue with separate `$http GET` request for dictionary from controller into separate file, as service. I'v tried look up for this, but I haven't found eglibe hints. Please for support.

Here are files:

app.js:

```
require('angular');
window.jQuery = $ = require('jquery');

var bootstrap = require('bootstrap-sass');
var HomeController = require( './controllers/HomeController' );
var dictionaryService = require('./services/dictionary.service');

var app = angular.module( 'app', [  ] );

app.controller( 'Controller', [ '$scope', '$http', '$log', HomeController ] );
```

controller.js

```
module.exports = function ( $scope, $http, $log ) {

    console.log( 'Hello from CTRL' );
    $scope.message = 'Two birds killed by stone!';

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/wsrp_crm/memcached'
    }).then( function successCallback( response ) {
        console.log( 'Memcached... OK' );
        $log.info( response );

        //I wannt to move this section below.
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/wsrp_crm/dictionary'
        } ).then( function successCallback( response ) {
            console.log( 'Dictionary... OK' );
            $log.info( response );
        }, function errorCallback( response ) {
            console.log( 'Dictionary... ERR' );
        } );

    }, function errorCallback( response ) {
        console.log( 'Error, can\'t resolve memcache' );
        $log.info( response );
    });
};
```

and directory structure:

```
├───node_modules
├───public
│   ├───bin
│   ├───css
│   ├───fonts
│   │   └───bootstrap
│   ├───img
│   └───js
└───src
    ├───app
    │   ├───config
    │   ├───controllers
    │   └───services
    ├───fonts
    ├───js
    ├───libs
    │   ├───bootstrap-sass
    │   ├───font-awesome
    │   └───jquery
    ├───partials
    └───scss
        ├───mixins
        └───variables
```

To be clear, I wannt move service into dir: ./services/dictionary.service.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, this is a solution:

**dictionary.service.js**

```
    app.services('DictionaryServices', dictionaryServices)
    app.$inject = ['$http', '$q']
    function dictionaryServices($http, $q) {
    this.getDictionary = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer()
        var url = '/api/url';

        $http.get(url)
        .success(deferred.resolve)
        .error(deferred.reject)

        return deferred.promise
    }
}
```

**controller.js**

Inject the DictionaryServices and call to DictionaryServices.getDictionary():

```
app.controller('MyController', myController)
myController.$inject = ['$scope', 'DictionaryServices']
function myController($scope, DictionaryServices) {

  DictionaryServices.getDictionary().then(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
  })

}
```

Comment: Don't use `$q` for this. It is a very common anti-pattern since `$http` already returns a promise. Also `success` and `error` are deprecated

Comment: @charlietfl oh! It´s true! $http return a promise... Thank you! Now I have to change all my services..... :)

Comment: that is right, now I am changing all $http requests, and this is reason why I rewrite previous version. success, err deprecated, but still idk how can I move this service to separated file. Most of solutions are depracated.